# Mounted gluster volume only accessible by root

Tags: nfs, cluster

I have a 2-node cluster with each node having two HDDs. The home directory of mpiuser is shared between the nodes via NFS(Used guide [here](http://byobu.info/article/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_cluster_with_Ubuntu)). The 2nd HDD of each node was used to create a gluster volume.
Now I want to mount the gluster volume(gv0) to a directory (lets say scratch) inside mpiuser and run mpi code in scratch. But when I mount gv0 /home/mpiuser/scratch only root can create files in it. Therefore mpiuser cannot run a code and generate files.

The way I mounted it was using

> sudo mount.glusterfs 192.168.0.100:/gv0 /home/mpiuser/scratch

I would appreciate any suggestions to get this to work.

Comment: I needed to set uid and gid of gluster volume to mpiuser.That solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set uid and gid of gluster volume to mpiuser.
To find uid executed

```
id -u <username>
```

and for gid

```
id -g <username>
```

To change uid of gluster volume

```
sudo gluster volume set <volume name> storage.owner-uid <uid>
```

To change gid

```
    sudo gluster volume set <volume name>  storage.owner-gid <gid>
```

Then mounted gluster volume on head node and shared mount point through NFS to slave node.